# Node.js EMFILE error on loop downloader

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have coded an img downloader with node.js, to backup some of our files(part of a huge application).

It is working in many cases, but today I had to apply the same operation to a new server, and I run into an EMFILE error (too many open files as per my research).

Could anyone explain to me why is that so, and what I could do to make it work?

Here's the code :

```
function dlImages(uniqImgs){
    var image = uniqImgs.shift();
    var imglink = image.link_img;
    var imgname = image.id+".jpg"
    if(imglink.indexOf('http')===-1){
        dlImages(uniqImgs);
    }
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('./WIDB/'+imgname);
    try{
        http.get(imglink, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function() {
                console.log(((totalImg-uniqImgs.length)/totalImg)*100);
                file.close();
                if(uniqImgs.length>0){
                    dlImages(uniqImgs);
                }else{
                    process.exit(66);
                }
            }).on('error', function(err){
                console.log(err);
                if(uniqImgs.length>0){
                    dlImages(uniqImgs);
                }else{
                    process.exit(66);
                }
            });
        }).on('error', function(err){
                console.log(err);
                    if(uniqImgs.length>0){
                        dlImages(uniqImgs);
                    }else{
                        process.exit(66);
                    }
            }).setTimeout(5000,function(){
                console.log(imglink + ' TIMEDOUT ');
                dlImages(uniqImgs);
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        dlImages(uniqImgs);
    }

}

db.getWILinks(function(links){  //gives back an array of objects = {id:xxx,link_img:xxx}
    uniqImgs = links;
    totalImg = uniqImgs.length;
    dlImages(uniqImgs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server, you can try to increase limits on opened files with `ulimit -n`.

If you can't change that, you can try to play around [graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) module.

Comment: root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/ # ulimit
unlimited

Comment: You need to set `ulimit -n`, not `ulimit`. If you run `ulimit -a`, you'll see all limits you have, look at "open files" there.